# How to make disabled control allow to be draggable or move by mouse?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, controls

I use dragging control by mouse

Problem is if **Control.Enabled = false**. Dragging can't work? Is there any method to overload to prevent this behavior?

```
    static void control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Control).Enabled = false;
        (sender as Control).Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
    }
    static void control_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Control).Enabled = true;
    //    (sender as Control).Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    static void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseLocation = e.Location;
        // turning on dragging
        draggables[(Control)sender] = true;
    }
    static void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // turning off dragging
        draggables[(Control)sender] = false;
    }
    static void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // only if dragging is turned on
        if (draggables[(Control)sender] == true)
        {
            var control = (sender as Control);

            control.Left = e.X + control.Left - mouseLocation.X;
            control.Top = e.Y + control.Top - mouseLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make it look disabled but not actually be?

Comment: I don't see why the Control should be disabled/enabled for this. Did you modify the original code for some reason? Because `mouseOffset` is never used and, even though this seems to be used an an extension method, there's no extension defined here.

Comment: no fully disabled Control.Enabled = false. Modified example anyway It not working as I can't copy whole code. Because SO prevent write much code with less words.

Comment: Take a snapshot of your control and only show that instead of your controls while it is in it's "draggable" state.

Comment: Not the point. Are `control_MouseEnter` and `control_MouseLeave` actually part of the original code? These two are not exactly related to dragging a Control at run-time and there's no reason at all to disable a Control for this. If you got this from a NuGet Package, then verify whether the Package has updates (using NuGet Package Manager), because, if the original code is what you presented, it's bugged.

Comment: You can use similar code just Mouse move move is enough for that. But problem here that Mouse events not working when Control.Enabled = false? I don't know why or how to overcome it.

Comment: Remove both `control_MouseEnter` and `control_MouseLeave`. If you want to change the Cursor, do it when you begin the operation and reset it when the operation completes. Also, check [SystemInformation.DragSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.dragsize) (since this is similar to Drag/Drop) to determine if/when the Control should be moved after a MouseDown event.

Comment: DragSize is readonly

Comment: Of course it's read-only. That's what you need to (or, can/could/would) do: read it. Did you check the Docs to see what is that parameter used for?

Comment: its useless property. Did you read the full question? Just try Control.Enabled then using the Mouse_Move to move Left,Top of Control and see what I mean

Comment: I don't mean dragging (by name I mean move control with MouseMove event)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=net-5.0) to trap WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Here I'm changing the caption of the form when the mouse is moved within pictureBox1.  It also tells you whether the left mouse button is down:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private MyFilter mf;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Enabled = false;

        mf = new MyFilter();
        mf.PreFilterMouseMove += Mf_PreFilterMouseMove;
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mf);
    }

    private void Mf_PreFilterMouseMove()
    {
        Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        if (pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt))
        {
            bool leftDown = (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left);
            this.Text = "leftDown = " + leftDown + " : position = " + pt.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "...not within pictureBox1...";
        }
    }
}

public class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
{

    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
    public delegate void dlgMouseMove();
    public event dlgMouseMove PreFilterMouseMove;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (PreFilterMouseMove != null)
                {
                    PreFilterMouseMove();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```